# Cloud9 IDE - equal symbol in filename

Tags: cloud9-ide

For my CMS, I need to create file with an equal symbol in the filename.

For the moment, it is not possible through the IDE, how can I request this feature?

Tks

Freed

Comment: equals sign is not allowed in a filename

Comment: @Freedux I have submitted the request for you. No need to do so yourself :)

Comment: I actually just tried this and was able to do it. What process are you going through to do it? I just right-clicked a file to rename it then typed it in with an equals sign. Shouldn't be any issues there.

Answer (score 0):

Cloud9 IDE does not have a specific place to make feature requests so you need to email their support for that.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @emmanuel It seems like a viable answer to me but I'm not set in my ways. This is the way I saw it:

Question: How do I request a feature?
Answer: By emailing support.

From my point of view, it seems like this is a viable answer. But maybe it's more of a critique?

Comment: @BradyDowling You can get support for about _every_ product by contacting support instead of asking in Stack Overflow. I would personally post it as a comment.

Comment: @Selcuk point taken, thanks for that. I've clarified a little in my response though next time I'll just leave it as a comment.